# Indexing With A Logical Test

Tags: r

I want a variable containing all the rows of dataframe `df` where `x` is greater than `y`. But for some reason I keep getting this strange error.

```
> x <- c(5,6,7,8,9,10)
> y <- c(1,7,8,29,0,1)
> 
> df <- data.frame(x, y)
> 
> x.is.more <- df[,"x" > "y"]; x.is.more
data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows
```

The code above should the same results as `x.is.more <- df[c(1,6),]` but for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: Try this `x.is.more <- df[df$x > df$y, ]`

Answer (score 3):

`subset` is probably the most straightforward way of doing this:

```
subset(df, x>y)
   x y
1  5 1
5  9 0
6 10 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` if you want to append the new variable to the existing data frame

```
> transform(df, x.is.more= x>y)
   x  y x.is.more
1  5  1      TRUE
2  6  7     FALSE
3  7  8     FALSE
4  8 29     FALSE
5  9  0      TRUE
6 10  1      TRUE
```

Use `with` if you just want a new variable

```
> x.is.more <- with(df, x>y)
> x.is.more
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you want to subset then try

```
> df[ with(df, x>y), ]  # equivalent to df[ x.is.more, ]
   x y
1  5 1
5  9 0
6 10 1
```

Or directly use `subset` function as in @James answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#dummy dataframe
df <- data.frame(x=c(5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 y=c(1,7,8,29,0,1))

#find x>y
x.is.more <- df[df$x > df$y, ]

#output
x.is.more
#   x y
#1  5 1
#5  9 0
#6 10 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I figured it out.

Instead of,

```
x.is.more <- df[,"x" > "y"]
```

I should have,

```
x.is.more <- df[x > y,]
```

Comment: Try removing x and y vectors `rm(x,y)` and running your code, it will fail.

Comment: Yep true. So there is no way to index through a logical test?